# show count rows with codeigntier

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

I want to count all the rows that are active today
But i can't get it to count

Model

```
public function aantal_externe_today()
{
$this->db->select_count('doel');
$this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00');
$data = $this->db->get();
return $data->result(); 
}
```

controller

```
public function count_ex()
{
$data['count_ex']  = $this->person->aantal_externe_today();
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
}
```

view

```
<td><center><h3><?= $count_ex[''] ?></h3></center></td>
```

Comment: show your table content

Comment: helpful for u  http://stensi.com/datamapper/pages/count.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this to work

modal

```
public function aantal_externe_today()
{
$this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}

function kapjes()
{
    $this->db->select_sum('aantal');//standard codeigniter method for getting sum
$this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00');
    $t= $this->db->get()->row();
   return $t->aantal;//
```

}

```
public function aantal_externe_besloten()
{
$this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00');
    $this->db->where('doel','2');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}

public function aantal_externe_gondel()
{
$this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00');
    $this->db->where('doel','3');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['aan'] = $this->person->aantal_externe_today();
    $data['brand'] = $this->person->kapjes();
    $data['besloten'] = $this->person->aantal_externe_besloten();
    $data['gondel'] = $this->person->aantal_externe_gondel();
    $this->load->view('nav_view',$data);
    $this->load->view('person_view');
    $this->load->view('footer');
```

view

```
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><center><h3><?php echo $aan;?></h3></center></td> 
    <td></td>
<td><center><h3><?php echo $besloten;?></h3></center></td> 
    <td></td> 
<td><center><h3><?php echo $brand;?></h3></center></td> 

    <td></td> 
<td><center><h3><?php echo $gondel;?></h3></center></td>  
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function aantal_externe_today()
{
   return $this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00')->count_all_results('doel');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be code like this:

Model

```
public function aantal_externe_today()
{
  $this->db->select_count('doel');
  $this->db->where('afmeldtijd','00:00:00');
  $data = $this->db->get();
  return array("result"=>$data->result(),"num_rows"=>$data->num_rows()); 
}
```

controller

```
public function count_ex()
{
  $data['count_ex']  = $this->person->aantal_externe_today();
  $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
}
```

view

```
<td><center><h3><?= $count_ex['num_rows'] ?></h3></center></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`$query->num_rows();`

to count all rows in codeigntier.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to count the no of record using active record class

Step1:

```
$query = $this->db->select("id")->get("tablename");
echo $query->num_rows();
```

Step2:

```
echo $this->db->count_all('my_table');
```

Comment: $query->num_rows(); this is inbuilt function in the codeignter.